# Angular 6 with bootstrap 4 - form validation e-mail

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4

I have form to submit email , I want to add validation, so that can not be empyt(requred), can not be invalid email eg `juventusSignedCr7@4.4,` etc    but when I add email eg `neymarPleaseStopeDiving` to my input and click submit  no error is  returned and data is submitted, only when I submit empty input i get the error message. email is required

Here is what i have done:

**UPDATE**

component.ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...............
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  angForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private flashMessages: FlashMessagesService,
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
    <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate class="form-element">
   <div class="form-group form-element_email">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" formControlName="email" #email />
            </div>
<div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['email'].dirty || angForm.controls['email'].touched)"
                class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
                  Email is required.
                </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <button (click)="addReview(email.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary form-element_btn">Book</button>
            </div>
      </form>
```

> Question

What is wrong with my code? please help newbie here though , thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also can use a regular expresion for the email field, something like this, in your input tag

```
<input type="email" class="form-control info" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

like this you call a function each time a user type inside, then in your Ts file, you declare the function that you put inside your input tag in your html

```
onChange(newValue) {
    const validEmailRegEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (validEmailRegEx.test(newValue)) {
        this.validEmail = true;
    }else {
      this.validEmail = false;
    }

  }
```

Just dont forget to declare the variable `validEmail` on the top of your file

```
validEmail:boolean = false
```

the constant `validEmail` is where you declare the regex expresion, the one that i put i really good for email validation,the method `test` is where you compare the expresion with the string, the method returns `true or false`
After that in your html button tag goes something like this.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block logBtn" [disabled]="!validEmail">ACCEDER</button>
```

i like this way because i can have full control of what i want in each input tag

Comment: I create the same method for another component it give this error ``true' is not assignable to type 'RegExp'``

Comment: no, man, see, the const validEmail inside the function is a regex expresion, the variable this.validEmail is the one that is boolean

Comment: done thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182151/angular-6-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined  can u check this?

Comment: Yep, like I said, I preffer this way 

Answer (score 4):

Angular 6 Provides input validators like email and required.

I generally don't want to allow `me@home` format and always expect a TLD (like .com, .net, .org, etc).
In addition to angular `email` validator I add my regex `pattern` to make it work.

```
<input type="email" name="email" #emailField="ngModel" pattern="^\S*[@]\S*[.]\S*$" email required />

<div class="help-block m-1" *ngIf="!emailField.valid && (emailField.touched || emailField.dirty)">
  <small>Invalid Email</small>
</div>
```

`email` will implement Angular's default email validator.

`required` will make this field as mandatory.

`pattern="^\S*[@]\S*[.]\S*$"` will make sure that there is a @ and a . followed by a string.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using FormGroup, what i did and works for me is add a validation when i create the FormGroup in the controller

```
FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email])
})
```

this validator is binded to the `[formGroup]="angForm"`

You can also create a custom validator

```
    import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateUrl(control: AbstractControl) {
  if (!control.value.startsWith('https') || !control.value.includes('.io')) {
    return { validUrl: true };
  }
  return null;
}

   /**
   a easy validator for an email could be something like this
    let a = "adas@sdfs.com"
    let b = a.split('@')
    if(b.length == 2){
      //ok
      let c = b[1].split('.')
      if(c.length >= 1){
        //ok
        //a have <something>@<something>.<something>
      }
    }
   **/
```

and import the validator in your controller

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidateUrl } from './validators/url.validator';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      websiteUrl: ['', [Validators.required, ValidateUrl]],
    });
  }
}
```

got the example from [here](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/)

Comment: check updated my question i fogot to add the component.ts file , check now

Comment: I just needed to change from ``email: ['', Validators.required]`` to   ``email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email])``  now user cant submit bad email eg fer#.com , but why when a user enter love@love  no erros is returned and its submitted , meaning `` example@example`` is it a valid email?

Comment: You are right, it's a problem in the implementation itself. You can anyway create your own Validator. Check this article: 
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/

Comment: Your Right and some one posted very postive answer to solve the issue , verry good solution for a beginner, Thanks for help bro