# Angular 6: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, html, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I am creating a simple form to submit data , email, city name and hotel name,  when I click submit i get this error:

> AboutComponent.html:79 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value'
>   of undefined

Here is what i have :
comment.js

```
// Comments Schema

const CommentsSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
},{
    collection: 'comments'
});

const Comments = module.exports = mongoose.model('Comments', CommentsSchema);
```

component.ts

```
addReview(email, name) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(email, name).subscribe(success => {
      this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
      // get the id
      this.activeRouter.params.subscribe((params) => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        let id = params['id'];
        this.moviesService.getComments(id)
          .subscribe(comments => {
            console.log(comments);
            this.comments = comments;
          });
      });
    }, error => {
      this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    });
  }
```

html

```
<form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-element">
          <div class="form-group form-element_email">
            <input type="email" class="form-control info" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" #email (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['email'].dirty || angForm.controls['email'].touched)"
                class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
                  Email is required.
                </div>
              </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_city">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
            <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.name" #name>{{city.name}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_hotel">
            <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
              <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.name" #name>{{hotel.name}}</option>

            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" (click)="addReview(email.value, name.value)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-element_btn" [disabled]="!validEmail">ACCEDER</button>
            </div>
      </form>
```

service.ts

```
 addReview(email, name): Observable<any> {
    const uri = `${apiUrl + this.addCommentsUrl}`;
    const obj = {
      email: email,
      name: name
    };
    return this.http.post(uri, obj);
  }
```

Note: when I remove name everything works fine , but i need also city name and hotel name to be inserted to my database together with email.

what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think templateRef var should be on select element instead option element.

Instead this

```
<option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.name" #name>{{city.name}}</option>
```

Can you try this:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
```

On a side note templateRef variable name should unique for each select element. You can not use same variable for two different elements.

See #name here:

```
1. <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.name" #name>{{city.name}}</option>

2. <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.name" #name>{{hotel.name}}</option>
```

Let me know, if that helps!

Comment: Hii after changing that templateRef variable to select  i get errror: ``Request URL: http://localhost:8000/movies/comments
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request``

Comment: That's your API server complaining about posted data. Make sure your webpage post required data to that endpoint. Put couple log statements during request to see what's going on. Also please upvote or accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: it helped little bit , after debugging I see email ="provided email" and name="" ; (name is empty)  on break point, so what do I need to change  ?

Comment: Not sure what might be wrong in your case. Can't say much without looking at full code.

Comment: what about model is okay? I have two select option both have to return the name value, city.name and hotel,name , and i have just one string as name, is it right?

Comment: What about something like this? (click)="addReview(email.value, select1.value || select2.value)"

Comment: Thanks that is what I wanted , now works perfectly, accepted the answer u can update your answer for other who will be interested, thanks again bro

Comment: Hii, can you chek this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191162/angular-6-and-bootstrap-4-date-picker